# overflow: hidden !important

Tags: html, css

На дисплеях с  большим расширением я скрываю скролл по горизонтали

```
@media (min-width: 1600px)
  div.k-scheduler-content {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

и возникает проблема что при выделении текста не идет прокрутка по вертикали   если срабатывает правило описанное выше, иначе все работает верно.
В чем тут проблема, ибо  скролл  имеет следующий код

```
div.k-scheduler-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

А скролл по вертикали не меняется и всегда виден 
Как решить эту проблему? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: вы что там по 10 метровый монитор верстаете ? раз на +1600 скролл

Comment: Вот ни разу не понятно, что вам надо. Какой элемент, куда перетягивается? 

может, вам не надо мучаться с `overflow`, а достаточно просто скрыть скроллбары? Тогда вот, например: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/

Comment: при разрешении больше 1600 пикселей горизонтальный скролл бар не нужен, так как контент полностью помещается, поэтому он прячется, а по вертикали скролл есть всегда и  если выделять текст  то  элемент внутри которго он находится не будет прокручиваться  по вертикали